# How to get data from table in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table, metatable

I have a table:

```
Table = {
    button = {},
    window = {},
    label = {},
    edit = {},
    error = {}
}
```

How I can get keys and values of the table?

I tried to get as:

```
for key, value in ipairs(Table) do
    for k, v in ipairs(key) do
       print(k, v)
    end
end
```

But it does't work.

Comment: `ipairs` means `(numerically) indexed pairs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ipairs` is for sequences(i.e, array-like tables). But `Table` in your code is not a sequence, you need to use `pairs` instead.

Another problem is that in `Table`, the keys are strings (`"button"`, `"window"` etc.). That's because in the table constructor, `button = {}` is equivalent to `["button"] = {}`.

You need to iterate the values which are (now empty) tables.

```
for key, value in pairs(Table) do
    for k, v in pairs(value) do
       print(k, v)
    end
end
```